# Dual NIC silently rejecting all incoming traffic from one interface

Tags: networking, routing, ip, ethernet, netplan

In my server, I have two ethernet cards:

- `enp0s17`, local IP `192.168.0.7`, router's public address `x.x.x.x`, netmask `255.255.255.255`
- `enp0s18`, local IP `172.16.0.7`, router's public address `y.y.y.y`, netmask `255.255.255.0`

On both networks, **any incoming traffic** of the two public IPs is **routed to the server**. So, actually any SSH, HTTP etc. going to `x.x.x.x` should be forwarded to `192.168.0.7` and any traffic to `y.y.y.y` should be forwarded to `172.16.0.7`.

Unfortunately, this is only working for **one of them at once**. Sometimes (after dis- and reconnecting the server to internet e.g. after reboot) this works for `enp0s17` and sometimes for `enp0s18` but **never for both** at the same time. (So, both routers are routing properly, seems to be an issue of the server.)

Same issue applies for outgoing traffic tested with `curl --interface enp0s1X ...`.

On the other hand, any **local traffic** is routing properly. In both networks, the server is always available on it's local IPs.

**Does anyone have an idea what might cause this issue or how to solve it?**

*For testing purpose I completely disabled the firewall, so, this shouldn't be the problem.*

*(Both interfaces are using IPv6 prefix delegation too but I just left it out as it's working properly.)*

Both routers are Ubiquiti EdgeRouters. IPs are statically given by the DHCP servers on the routers. Network configuration is done using `netplan`. Using Ubuntu 20.04.

My `netplan` config:

```yaml
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
       enp0s17:
          dhcp4: yes
          dhcp6: yes
       enp0s18:
          dhcp4: yes
          dhcp6: yes
```

default route:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp0s17 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.7 metric 100 
default via 172.16.0.1 dev enp0s18 proto dhcp src 172.16.0.7 metric 100 
172.16.0.0/16 dev enp0s18 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.0.7 
172.16.0.1 dev enp0s18 proto dhcp scope link src 172.16.0.7 metric 100 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-b20299b5e473 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-ba582f6855c2 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp0s17 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.7 
192.168.0.1 dev enp0s17 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.7 metric 100
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's not the router.  but what is the default route on your server?

Comment: @RonTrunk Thank you. As both routers are routing properly to the server as well as to other devices I expect it to be due to the server. Moreover, I added the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp0s17 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.7 metric 100 
default via 172.16.0.1 dev enp0s18 proto dhcp src 172.16.0.7 metric 100
```

Your problem is you have two default routes -- you can only have one.  Your incoming data is fine.  But when your server sends a reply, since you have two default routes, the server alternates between the two routes. *i.e.*, half the packets go the wrong direction.

You need to pick one interface for your default, and you will need to add explicit routes for your other networks.

Comment: Thank you very much. I removed the unwanted default route by `ip route delete default dev enp0s18 table main` and then followed [this excellent guide](http://www.rjsystems.nl/en/2100-adv-routing.php) to create a second route for my second interface.

Comment: @RonTrunk actually there's no load balancing between the two "default" routes: all use the first displayed. That's different from routes using the multipath route with "nexthop" syntax.